# morphism on the commutator subgroup of the free group/picture-hanging-puzzle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology

Let $F_n=\langle x_1,\dots,x_n \rangle$ denote the free group on $n$ generators. Let
\begin{align}
\varphi:F_n\rightarrow \prod_{i=1}^n\langle x_1,\dots,x_n \mid x_i=e \rangle
\end{align}
be the canonic morphism making one of the generators trivial in each entry. I want to understand $\ker \varphi$. Its clear that $\ker\varphi \subset [F_n,F_n]$. Ultimately I am interested in finding the element in $\ker\varphi$ with the least symbols for each $n$. Obviously when $n=2$ this is $[x_1,x_2]$ up to relabelling of the generators. In the case $n=3$ it probably is $[x_1,x_2]x_3[x_2,x_1]x_3^{-1}$.

Motivation for this is the [picture-hanging-puzzle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.3602.pdf) from topology where we you want to hang a picture on $n$ nails such that removing a nail makes the picture fall. It is known that there are solutions $\leq 2n^2$ symbols long, I'm just wondering if there is anything with less than $n^2$ symbols.

Is there anything more known about this?

Comment: It's possible that I didn't understand the definition of $\varphi$. Let's say $n=3$. We get
$$
\varphi([x_1,x_2])=(e,e,[x_1,x_2]).
$$
Or maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: Yes, we essentially 'delete' the $i$-th generator in each entry. The goal is that the element then completely reduces.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. It's possible that $\ker\varphi=[F,\ldots,F]$ ($n$-th member of the lower center series).

Comment: @kabenyuk I don't think so. In your example with $n=3$, the Engel element $[x_1,x_2,x_2]$ lies in $F_3$ but is not in the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of the shortest elements in $\ker \varphi$ is determined in the following paper:

*Gartside, Paul; Greenwood, Sina*, [**Brunnian links**](https://doi.org/10.4064/fm193-3-3), Fundam. Math. 193, No. 3, 259-276 (2007). [ZBL1111.57006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1111.57006).

For some reason the doi link seems to be broken. Use this link instead: https://eudml.org/doc/282667

Assuming $n = 2^m + k \in [2^m, 2^{m+1})$, they show that the minimal length of a nontrivial element of $\ker\varphi$ is exactly $2^m(2^m+3k)$ (Theorem 7), and they also determine the number and structure of the minimizing words.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I know what $\ker \varphi$ is. To my understanding, it's not the $n$-th lower center series (correct me if I'm wrong) but a subgroup of it. We take some word in $\ker\varphi$. We can order elements using commutators until we get all of the $x_1$ and $x_1^{-1}$ in the beginning and then $x_2$ and $x_2^{-1}$ after that. It is clear that for each generator there is also the same number of inverses (i.e. the solution is in $[F_n,F_n]$), so all the stand-alone generators (basic commutators of weight 1) reduce.

It becomes interesting once we look at the rest, it will turn out that the solution consists only of a product of basic commutators where *all generators have to somehow appear in each basic commutator*.

To see this, we start with some generator $x_i$ which is not in all of the basic commutators (if it wouldn't exist, we would be done). We take all of the basic commutators which do not contain $x_i$ and move them to the left of the word, starting from the right, using commutators (like before), meaning we insert
\begin{align*}
wv=vw[w,v]
\end{align*}
if $w,v$ are basic commutators and $w$ contains $x_i$ and $v$ doesn't. It is important to note that the commutator $[w,v]$ we leave behind contains $x_i$. This way we get a word of the form
\begin{align*}
w_{\not x_i}w_{x_i}
\end{align*}
where $w_{\not x_i}$ is a product of basic commutators out of which *none* contain $x_i$ whereas $w_{x_i}$ is a product of basic commutators out of which *all* contain $x_i$.

Now if we 'delete' the generator $x_i$, the word $w_{\not x_i}$ does not change while $w_{x_i}$ will disappear. We can deduce that $w_{\not x_i}=e$ because we started with an element in $\ker \varphi$.

We can keep doing this until all generators are in every basic commutator.

On the other hand we see that every such product of commutators will also result in a solution. I therefore claim that $\ker\varphi$ is the group generated by the set of basic commutators which contain all generators $x_1,\dots, x_n$.